# Horizontally flip a canvas image?

Tags: canvas, playn

How horizontally flip a canvas image ?

I tried with

```
  CanvasImage ci = graphics().createImage(width, height);
  ci.canvas().scale(-1.0F, 1.0F);
  ci.canvas().drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply flip the scale, as that will result in rendering from 0 to -width which will be outside the bounds of the image on which you are drawing.

You need to translate by the width of the image, so that you render from width to 0:

```
CanvasImage ci = graphics().createImage(width, height);
ci.canvas().translate(image.width(), 0);
ci.canvas().scale(-1.0F, 1.0F);
ci.canvas().drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```